# How to correctly use Java generics for an array implementation of an ADT

Tags: java, arrays, generics, adt

I am trying to teach my students the proper way to use Java generics.  I am teaching a data structures course, so I want them working with arrays and their own linked lists, not with the Java Collections (for example no ArrayList).  A typical issue is providing an array implementation for an ADT.  Here is an example where I am trying to use a heap implemented as an array to provide a Priority Queue.  I would like to support a priority queue of any kind of data objects so I use a generic
I start with an interface:

```
public interface PriQue<E> {
    void insert(int pri, E data);
    E remove(); // return null when empty
    boolean isEmpty();
}
```

Then I implemented it:

```
public class ArrayHeap<E> implements PriQue<E> {
//private class Entry<E> {  hides E of ArrayHeap which means remove fails
    private class Entry {  // uses E of ArrayHeap
        int pri;
        E data;
    . . .
    } // end of Entry
    Entry heap[];
    int cnt;
    public ArrayHeap(int size) {
        // heap = new Entry[size]; can not create generic array error
        // heap = (Entry[])new Object[size]; blows up on a cast error
        heap = (Entry[])new Object[size];
        cnt = 0;
    }
    . . .
    public E remove() {
        E tmp = (E)heap[--cnt].getData(); //bad don't want to cast
        // trickle down code here
        return tmp;
    }
```

Since the interface is parameterized I use the same generic in the implementing class – I think this is ok.
I need to create an array of entries that will hold a priority and the corresponding data item.  So I create a private class.  Here my problem begins.  If I leave the parameter out then since it is part of ArrayHeap it should pick up the E generic form there.  This compiles but blows up when I try to create an array of Entry.  Alternately I can have an explicit generic parameter to Entry.  If I pick E it will “hide” E from ArrayHeap and when I try to remove an E from the array it does not realize it is the same E as the ArrayHeap E.  If I name it something else, say V, then it cannot assign an E to a V and I cannot store any data.  I think this is a fairly common situation in implementing a data structure.
I’ve tried reading http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ104
But it does not cover a nested class (and its mostly about what does not work)
I’ve tried reading the code for the Java collections map implementation and I don’t see what is different.

Comment: You declare your inner class with its _own_ generic type - say `V`. Then, when you declare the _instance_ if the inner class you use `E` - `Entry<E> heap[];`. This is when you set `V` equal to `E`. For an example take a look at [the source for `AbstractMap`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractMap.java) which has exactly the same pattern. You cannot create generic arrays; this is your main issue it seems.

Comment: How does `remove()` fails, when you use `Entry<E>` instead of `Entry`?

Comment: Have you looked at the source code for HashMap on GrepCode? It uses a nested class with generics: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.Entry Also, I don't understand what you mean when you say "should pick up the E generic form there". Can you clarify?

Comment: @BoristheSpider is right. You have to declare it Entry<E> heap[];

Comment: on the @Rohit Jain comment if I declare Entry

Comment: on the @Rohit Jain comment if I declare Entry private class Entry<E> then in the remove E tmp = heap[--cnt].getData(); I get a type mismatch can not convert from Object to E

Comment: On @BoristheSpider AbstractMap comment
I've been looking at the Map code.
AbstractMap does not actually create any space
it's subclasses do.
For example HashMap declares a table like this:
 transient Entry[] table;
And gets space for it like this:
        table = new Entry[capacity];
This looked a lot like what I was doing
However, I was starting to spend more time pulling in enough supporting 
classes to make it compile, so I posted a question.

Comment: On @BoristheSpider comment use 
    Entry<E> heap[];
this does fix the compile error on the remove
However, 
    heap = (Entry[])new Object[size];
blows up, which is why I abandoned the approach
However, I change to:
    heap = new Entry[size];
and things work although I get a compiler warning
Type safety: The expression of type ArrayHeap.Entry[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to ArrayHeap<E>.Entry<E>[]

Comment: On @BoristheSpider comment
Changing it it:
    heap = new Entry<E>[size];
Gives a compiler error
 Cannot create a generic array of ArrayHeap<E>.Entry<E>
which I normally deal with by creating an Object array
and casting - which in this case blows up at runtime.

So this approach can work by living with the type safety
warning and the warning in the class declaration 
The type parameter E is hiding the type E
which may be as good as it gets with Java generics

Comment: If you teach CS, you may be interested in the new [CS Educator's Stack Exchange](http://cseducators.stackexchange.com) (though since it's still in private beta, it's easiest to enter [through here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
public class ArrayHeap<E> implements PriQue<E> {
    private static class Entry<E> {
        int pri;
        E data;

        // ...

        public E getData() {
            return data;
        }
    }

    Entry<E>[] heap;
    int cnt;

    public ArrayHeap(int size) {
        heap = (Entry<E>[])new Entry<?>[size];
        // or: heap = new Entry[size];
        cnt = 0;
    }

    public E remove() {
        E tmp = heap[--cnt].getData();
        return tmp;
    }

    // ...
}
```

The key is that `Entry` is changed to become a static nested class, rather than a non-static inner class (which would still be dependent on your outer class's type parameters). Then you can actually create an array of `Entry<?>`, and do a cast from that.

Comment: You can even do `Entry<E>[] heap = new Entry[size]` and trade the cast for a compiler warning. Worth pointing out that the OP should stop using legacy array notation too.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yep, indeed. (And in fact even the cast will cause a compiler warning.)

Comment: @BoristheSpider: except that raw types should be avoided

Comment: @newacct if you're in the business of abusing arrays to get a generic type then rawtypes are probably the least of your problems. Although I agree entirely, rawtypes are evil.

Comment: Yes, all these @BoristheSpider comments suggest Java may not be terribly usable.  But, somehow folks use it.

Comment: Adding the static to the inner class is very interesting and in fact digging through the Java Collections HashMap code (now that I know what to look for) I see they do this as well.  Adding the static removes a warning "The type parameter E is hiding the type E" which seems a good thing.  I note that it also incorperates @BoristheSpider change to add a paramiterized type to the array declaration (Entry<E> heap[];).  Thanks Chris

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that because Java erases generic type parameters at compile-time, it's not safe to create an array containing a generic type.  You're going to need a cast somewhere: the best you can do is to hide it away in helper functions.

If you look at the JDK implementation of `ArrayList`, for example, you'll see that at its heart is an `Object[]`.

Comment: I'm well aware that the decision to to erase generic type at the end of compile time, made to avoid having to update JVM which was considered to widely distirbuted to changed, means everything in Java (other than primatives) ends up as an Object by runtime.  The question is - is this problem contained enough to use Java to teach ADT's.  Given that the Java collections class seems to work ok, it would seem that there is some way to do it.